# ASP.NET Configuration doesn't show up in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a problem with VS2008: When I create a new ASP.Net website, no database shows up in the AppData folder. I create a new one via the server browser, and then apply "Add existing item" on the AppData folder to "import" the database. Is this the right way to do it?
Plus when I chose Website / ASP.Net configuration, my CPU works for a brief moment, but the configuration page is not opened in the browser.
In VS2005 it worked quite differently, as the database was created automatically and also the configuration thing worked. Am I missing something here in VS2008?
I already tried to find an answer in the MSDN tutorials, but they don't seem to do something special / different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No database shows up because you have to create one. Right click on App_Data and select "Add New Item".

For the Web.config, check your Event logs to see if your browser is throwing an error. You can see this under Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer > Application

Finally, a suggestion. As a programmer, is is a good idea to get familiar with the code in the Web.config file and how to edit directly.

[An older but pretty good tutorial.](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/web-config-file-demystified/)

Comment: Thanks, I got it running right now :) Yeah I'll have to take a look at the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to do it that way.  I simply take the `.MDF` file and drop it into the `App_Data` folder, and do it that way.

Edit: I normally make [ASP.NET Web Applications instead of websites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(VS.80).aspx#wapp_topic5), which may be why it's easier.